# What connotation does "to fork one's repo" have?

Tags: idioms, slang, connotation, software, appropriate

In a [recent news item](http://techcrunch.com/2013/03/21/a-dongle-joke-that-spiraled-way-out-of-control/), an employee was fired partly for making jokes about "big dongle" and "forking repos", which were [alleged to be inappropriate sexual jokes](https://twitter.com/adriarichards/statuses/313417655879102464). The employee admitted the dongle joke but defended the other joke,

> While I did make a big dongle joke about a fictional piece hardware
>   that identified as male, no sexual jokes were made about forking. My
>   friends and I had decided forking someone’s repo is a new form of
>   flattery (the highest form being implementation) and we were excited
>   about one of the presenters projects; a friend said “I would fork that
>   guys repo” The sexual context was applied by Adria, and not us.

What inappropriate meaning can be mistaken from "forking one's repo?" and how can it be taken that way? [Forking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29) sounds like a legitimate terminology in software development.

Comment: Forking also sounds like something you might do with another person in the privacy of your own home, or maybe the bathroom stall at work.

Comment: @KitFox in that case, why would anyone do it to other people's repo?

Comment: Are you kidding? Some people will fork anything.

Comment: Dude, are you forking serious?

Comment: "[Frack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frak_(expletive)) this!", I commanded and the miners sprang into action.

Comment: Now now, minors aren't to be fracking.

Comment: Guys, any real answer? Why am I getting downvoted?

Comment: Louis, they apparently want you to do more first-hand research on the subject yourself.

Comment: I almost choked on my forking beef sandwich over @jwpat7's comment!  These comments should come with "choke" alerts! ;-)

Comment: The opening of the sentence, "I would fork that..." is similar to a common phrasing of sexual suggestions. That probably contributed to the way the remark was interpreted.

Answer (score 13):

*Fork* sounds like *fuck*.

If you need to make a vulgar joke, it doesn't really matter if the rest of it makes sense. Just being made in context of other vulgar jokes may be enough. (Whether it was intended as a joke, vulgar or otherwise, is another matter.)

*Forking a repo* is legitimate software terminology. It means to take a copy of another person or group's software (repository) so as to continue development independently.  There may be the intention of contributing your changes back at a later date, or the fork may represent a split or schism in the developer community, with different aims.

As an extreme example, here's a diagram of Linux distribution forks, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29):

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg/131px-Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg.png

Forking someone's repo certainly can be praise. It's validation not only that their software is useful for you, but that you want to help continue it's development, and often voluntarily.

This use of *fork* has been in use since 1980 and the diagram shows it naturally follows on from earlier uses such as a fork in the road.

In 1605 J. Sylvester wrote the earliest known example of this particular *fork* as a verb:

> In two faire Branches forking
>    fruitfully.

Comment: Um, this comes from the fork(2) syscall.

Comment: @tchrist: Does fork(2) naturally follow on from earlier uses? :)

Comment: Perhaps vaguely.  But the crucial aspect of having a perfect duplicate of some other thing at the onset is the key point, whether forking a process or a project.  And the project sense absolutely derives from the process sense; I guarantee it.

Comment: @tchrist: Wikipedia [agrees with you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)#Etymology).

Comment: Also related is the [Fork spell from Magic: The Gathering](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=200), which creates a duplicate of an instant or sorcery spell. Richard Garfield seems to have been a Unix hacker. :)

Comment: The reason why the specific phrase used is so extremely easy to interpret as a sexual joke is not only that _fork_ sounds like a minced version of _fuck_, but that the sentence follows an archetypal dirty-comment formula: **I’d [verb] his/her [object]**. This formula can basically _always_ be taken as something sexual—it doesn't even have to make sense. “I'd rotate his cuffs” makes no real anatomical sense, but would be immediately understandable as a dirty way of saying, “I'd hit it” (as they say on the Internet).

Answer (score 1):

I think the inappropriateness of "forking one's repo" stems from the way it is phrased. I'd never seen *fork* applied to a repo before (maybe others have), only to projects, so for example someone might say:

> I've forked Linux.

The way they've phrased it, though, is more like:

> I've forked Torvald's repo.

Which does sound a lot more sexual, as you can easily imagine *repo* standing for any "forkable" body part.

Given that telling women that they're fuckable is a widespread sexist "praise" (it equates their value with their sexual desirableness), given that the fired guy considered telling that someone's repo was forkable was a praise, and given the close correspondence between the two idioms, I cannot see how saying it the way they did could *not* be sexist, though I doubt they were conscious of it.

Furthermore, in the specific case of the fired guy saying:

> The sexual context was applied by Adria, and not us.

It is incorrect. Adria said:

> He said he would be interested in forking the repo and continuing development.
>
> That would have been fine until the guy next to him […] began making sexual forking jokes.

So she clearly didn't ascribe a sexual innuendo to the original use (though, as shown by the beginning of my post, *I* think it is there, albeit subconsciously).

What I would like to know is how did they go from "forking someone's repo" to a sexual joke about big dongles *without* an intermediate step of an overtly sexual forking joke. It's not like forking a project (or a repo) and hardware dongles have anything in common that would link them.

Nothing in this episode warrants anybody losing their job or getting rape and death threat.

Comment: "Fork a repo" is extremely common language on the popular open-source website Github. They even have a help page with It as a title: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

Comment: "you can easily imagine repo standing for any 'forkable' body part." <- This makes me think of Repo Men, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Intended or not, the interpreted pun or bowdlerised euphemism concerns the word *fork* and is unlikely to have anything to do with *repo*. While Urban Dictionary [has a number of entries](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fork&defid=1376788) (*NSFW*) for the use of *fork* as a slang term, the mixed voting suggests niche usage.

Answer (score 0):

Forking is when you make a new branch on a tree of some kind, e.g. a timeline.  "Forking a repo" means to create a new branch on a source code repository.  It probably sounds sexual because "spooning" is sexual.  Spoon, fork...you get it.

Comment: *Fork* sound like *fuck*. I think that's more likely than analogies to spooning. But this just shows there's more than one way to read unintended meanings (and be offended) from an apparently innocent comment.

Answer (score 0):

"Fork" sounds like a [minced oath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) for "fuck".

[image: fork you]

[image: fork me]

This kind of wordplay has been used before, such as by github using "fork you" ("fuck you") and "fork me" ("fuck me"), when it was into [brogramming](http://edition.cnn.com/2012/05/07/tech/web/brogrammers) ("bro" + "programmer") style humor.

Answer (score -1):

In IT context the meaning is quite obvious: it's branching of some codebase.

The usage 'fork someone's repo' sounds already weird, because the repository is the set of many branches, which can be forked etc. and usually repository belongs to the company and can't be attributed to single person, like the branch.

If something sounds weird, people will look for some loose associations. It happens to be, that a heck of loose associations are of sexual nature.

Instead of the similarities between 'fork' and other words, 'fork' in the IT context means 'to multiply', which is already close to 'breed'. 'Repo' is close to 'codebase' which, when referring to the person, can mean 'genetic code' as well.

The quotation makes no doubts about the intentions of the speaker. He actually admits going around company's policy about sexual jokes.

Comment: I _sincerely_ doubt whether someone saying "uh, uh, I'd fork that guy's repo, uh, uh" like a teenage hormone-bomb would _actually_ have enough linguistic and biological brain capacity running at that moment to consider things like _breeding_ and _genetics_, let alone some quite entangled simile with his actual work environment. What is more likely? "I'd fork that guy's repo, uh, uh. Get it? His 'repo'. uh, uh" or "I'd fork that guys repo. You understand? I insinuated I would breed based on his genetic code." [Sheldon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheldon_Cooper) might say the latter...

Comment: @oerkelens you forget that the guy making that joke was no monkey but IT specialist